# React - Table onClick collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, html-table, redux

I have data with parents and children and want to render this as a table. When you click on a parent the children should collapse.

I tried doing this by giving children a className of Parent. So clicking the parent would select all classes of the same name. 
I read that in React you should not make the changes in the DOM. As if it wasn't hard enough already!

Here is my table. (While were at it, I'm rendering a new tbody per parent, because React cries about returning proper react elements.. I would really like it to be just all s, if possible)

```
    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>value</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                {this.props.data.items.map(function (parent) {
                    return (
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td >{parent.name}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {parent.children.map(function (child) {
                            return (
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{child.name}</td>
                                    <td>{child.value}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                        </tbody>
                    )
                })}
            </table>
        )
    }
}
```

Data looks like this

```
[{
  "name": "Food", "children": [
    {"name": "Apple", "value": 5.6},
    {"name": "Banana", "value": 2.2},
    {"name": "Peer", "value": 1.6},
  ]
},
{
  "name": "Drink", "children": [
    {"name": "Cola", "value": 5.6},
    {"name": "Juice", "value": 2.2},
    {"name": "Water", "value": 1.6},
  ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an onClick event handler on the parent td `<td><button value={parent.name} onClick={this.handleClick}>{parent.name}</button></td>`

Then you will need a handleClick method in your component that fires a redux action and updates the state. You will need a new property in your data structure to store whether the parent is open or closed. Something like `[{"name": "Food", "children": [...], "open": true}]`.

Now you can check for the property in the parent and only display the children based on the bool
`{parent.open ? parent.children.map(...) : ''}`

Final result would look a bit like this

```
 handleClick(event) {
   this.props.toggleParent(event.target.value);
 }
 render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>value</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                {this.props.data.items.map(function (parent) {
                    return (
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><button value={parent.name} onClick={this.handleClick}>{parent.name}</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        {parent.open ? parent.children.map(function (child) {
                            return (
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{child.name}</td>
                                    <td>{child.value}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        }.bind(this) : ''}
                        </tbody>
                    )
                })}
            </table>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks spirift! I like this answer, but I have 1 issue. I have the function in a parent component and passes it down as a prop. Now when clicking this: onClick={() => {this.props.handleClick(event)}}. It tell me that this is undefined.

Comment: Hard to know for sure without seeing the code but I think you can use the onClick `onClick={this.props.handleClick}` event is automatically passed as the first argument. Perhaps you will need the anonymous arrow function but that would be written as: `onClick={(event) => this.props.handleClick(event)}`

Comment: Fixed it by using () => in the parent and not the child. I also used arrow functions in both the map functions or I would need to bind both, instead of the just the 1 you did. Thanks!